# Android check what fragment sent onClick action

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have to build a simple app where I have 3 fragments, each contains 1 button.
If one of these buttons is pressed a site should load within a webview which is contained by the main activity. So far i have the basic callback to the activity working, but my question is. How do I check which button is pressed? Since they all seem to send the same view to the activity. I have tried to use the view.setTag() method but I couldn't get it to work.

Here is some of my code:

MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnApple){
        wvResult.loadUrl("http://www.apple.com");
    }else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnMic){
        wvResult.loadUrl("http://www.microsoft.com");
    }else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnOracle){
        wvResult.loadUrl("http://www.oracle.com");
    }

}
```

One of the fragment classes (each is different in the names (apple, microsoft and oracle), the rest is exactly the same):

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.btn_a, container, false);

    btnApple = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnApple);

    btnApple.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callBack.onClick(v.getRootView());
        }
    });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    callBack = (View.OnClickListener) activity;
}
```

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass *v* in your callback method (not *v.getRootView()*) because **it** is the view which was clicked.

[View.getRootView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRootView()) retrieves the root view element of view hieararchy, which is most likely one of the *ViewGroup* classes (*LinearLayout*, *RelativeLayout*, ...). That is the view which **contains** the clicked button.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed something I forgot about :)